# calling a procedure/package from a view

Tags: oracle, view, package, procedure, calling-convention

I have an oracle view which gets updated as part of a built in mechanism. I need to use the data of that view for further processing in a separate process. I have written a procedure (using cursors) in a package for carrying out that processing. But cannot understand how to **call** the same to carry out the execution. Is there any way I can **call the package/procedure from the view** itself?
My requirement is that the package/procedure should be called for execution after the data in the view gets updated through that existing built in mechanism.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't call a procedure from a query. And a plain view doesn't get updated - it's just a stored query. (A *materialized* view does, so maybe that's what you mean?). Maybe if you explain the mechanism you are using know we'll be able to see what you are trying to achieve and how to do it.

Comment: Actually we are using a planning tool and the tables are populated after the planning engine is executed. The view is created using one of those tables among others.

Comment: You shouldn't recreate the view after updating the tables it's based on. Querying the view will always see the latest data. You need to call the procedure as part of the overall process, after however you are executing the planning engine.